# Is there a projection to a subobject of an object in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $C$ be an abelian category (maybe, plus some nice properties.)

Let $X$ be an object of $C$ and let $i:Y\to X$ be a (representative of) subobject of$X$.

**Question 1**: Is there a projection $p$ from $X$ to $Y$ so that $p\circ i=\mathrm{id}_{Y}$?

I came across this question when I tried to prove that $X$ is a direct sum of $Y$ and $X/Y$. (I am not sure if this is true.)

**Question 2** If an object $X$ has a subject $Y$, is $X=Y\oplus X/Y$? How do I make sense of $X/Y$ in an abelian category? Is it the cokernel of the monomorphism of the subobject $i: Y \to X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no to both questions. When such a map exists, we say that $Y$ is a direct summand of $X$. If all subobjects of objects in an abelian category $C$ are direct summands, then $C$ is said to be *semisimple*, and this is a very restrictive condition; as its name suggests, if $C = \text{Mod}(R)$ is the abelian category of modules over a ring, then this condition holds iff $R$ is a semisimple ring in the usual sense.

In particular, $R = \mathbb{Z}$ is not semisimple. The subobject $2\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is not a direct summand. Equivalently, the [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence)

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$$

does not [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma), and $\mathbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. This reflects the existence of interesting [Ext groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor) in this category.

You are correct that $X/Y$ is the cokernel of the inclusion.